# 'Editor' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tsx

What is the type error, when I use ckeditor or editor in my Next.js application, anyone can?

```
'Editor' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'Editor' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'ReactElement<{ ref: RefObject<HTMLElement>; id: string; }, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
        Property 'children' is missing in type 'ReactElement<{ ref: RefObject<HTMLElement>; id: string; }, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>' but required in type 'ReactPortal'.ts(2786)
```

[image]

The editor component code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
interface ckEditorProps {
  data?: any;
  editorChangeHandler?: (e: any, editor: any) => void;
}
function TextEditor({ data, editorChangeHandler }: ckEditorProps) {
  return <CKEditor editor={ClassicEditor} data={data} onChange={editorChangeHandler} />;
}
export default TextEditor;
```

When I will use `yarn build`, it will not build.

Comment: Can you add code for `Editor` component?

Comment: import React, { Component } from "react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";

interface ckEditorProps {
  data?: any;
  editorChangeHandler?: (e: any, editor: any) => void;
}

function TextEditor({ data, editorChangeHandler }: ckEditorProps) {
  return (
    <CKEditor
      editor={ClassicEditor}
      data={data}
      onChange={editorChangeHandler}
    />
  );
}

export default TextEditor;

Comment: I'm assuming there is an issue with `@types/react` in your `node_modules`. Can you run this: `rm -rf node_modules && yarn install --frozen-lockfile` and then try to build, and check if its fine?